# WSL upgrade from version 1 to version 2 causes network problems

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu on my Windows 10 host machine and lately needed to change WSL version from 1 to 2 (using command `wsl --set-version`).
It looks like after that operation my Ubuntu lost network connection. My `/etc/resolve.conf` file looks correct.

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.28.80.1
```

Any ideas on what might have caused that and how to fix it?

EDIT:
I tried changing `resolv.conf` with correct `wsl.conf` configuration (`generateResolvConf = false`). I have compression of Packages folder turned off as someone mentioned. None of the solutions helped.

Comment: Here is a step by step guide how to fix this, changing the /etc/resolv.conf file and disabling "Fast Startup" in Win10: https://kontext.tech/article/1042/wsl-2-network-issue-solutions-on-ubuntu-and-other-distros Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633406/unable-to-access-network-from-wsl2 here: https://stephenreescarter.net/wsl2-network-issues-and-win-10-fast-start-up/ and here for Win11: https://superuser.com/questions/1691097/wsl2-cannot-access-the-internet-on-windows-11
Please check before opening a new question or state what you have tried so the community can help better. Thx

Comment: @Lorberta I already tried all that. It didn't help. Added that information in original post as suggested.